# importing wav music files in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, import, audio

I download an album in `wav` format.

I would like to import it in iTunes and upload it to my iphone 8 plus.
I am using `iTunes` version `12.10.2.3` on `Windows 7`.

For some reasons I can't import the album on iTunes (I tried both drag and dropping and using the menu *File-> Add Folder to Library*).

I tried to convert the album in mp3 format and doing the same operation.

I can't import it, and I receive no error message from `iTunes`.
If I double click on the files them selves the album plays correctly from iTunes (but it's not imported hence I can't upload it to my iphone).

Does any one know how can I solve this?